# How can I retrieve the full text of a tweet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, python-twitter

I run the code below and even I set as parameter `tweet_mode='extended'` i do not get the full text of the retrieved tweets. Can anybody help me to fix it?

```
import tweepy

consumer_key ='xxxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxxx'

access_token = 'xxxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxxx'

# create our authentication variable
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

cursor= tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="obama",tweet_mode='extended', lang="en", date='2017-11-13', days_ago=9).items(5)

for tweet in cursor:
    print (tweet.created_at,tweet.full_text)
```

Here are the corresponded results.

```
2017-11-21 13:55:20 Another one of Obama's poor little underprivileged Black ladies, oppressed by Whites? 
2017-11-21 13:55:20 RT @PoliticalShort: Remember when it was considered immoral to question whether Obama’s 20-year patronage at Wright’s radical church could…
2017-11-21 13:55:20 RT @IosrscIub: i had a dream that i was trying to find a fruit scale in walmart to weigh my pomegranates and then obama stopped me, took th…
2017-11-21 13:55:19 @WhereIs_Billy @FoxNews No Ure wrong! He saved them from possible yrs in jail there Dumb Ass! Look Wht happened to Otto cause Racist OBAMA did NOTHING! Mayb all u liberals shld go to N K good bye!  No F...... Respect! MAGA MAGA
2017-11-21 13:55:19 RT @oldhippiebroad: This is no judge. He’s politician all the way. He’s a disgrace. #UraniumOneScandal #LockThemAllUp
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter doesn't deliver the full text of Retweets (RT).

It looks like the 1st and 4th messages are complete, the others with RT after the time stamp have been truncated by Twitter with '...' at the end.

The last RT message is short enough not to have been truncated.